# Animation not working when I scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animate.css

I am using `animate.css` and trying to apply animation classes to different sections in a page. The animations are working but not when I scroll to that particular section. So now if I want to see a particular section animation then I will have to refresh. So I want to know how can I achieve the animation on the scroll.

See full code here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxoaWP

Below is the Javascript am using to achieve it. Not sure where am I going wrong. Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(event)) {
        var y = $.(this).scrollTop();
        if (y >= 300) {
            $('#about').addClass('animated shake');
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(event)) {
        var y = $.(this).scrollTop();
        if (y >= 600) {
            $('#about').addClass('animated shake');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: better to use animate.css using with wow js plugin

Comment: I used this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ADmKnE4_DqQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested you can use wow.js which will make it easier.
Check this:

```css
.quot{
 text-align:center;
 outline: 3px solid #BFBFBF;

}

#vision{
 font-size: 22px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.1/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.js"></script>


<script>
new WOW().init();
</script>



<div class="row" >
  <div class="">
    <div id="about" class="section wow bounceInUp scrollspy">
      <div class="container">
        <h2 class="wow bounceInDown" style="text-decoration:underline;text-align:center;font-weight:bold;font-family:Comic Sans MS">About Us</h2><br><br>
          <div class="wow bounceInUp">
            <h5 style="color:#446CB3;padding-top:30px;text-decoration:underline;font-weight:bold;font-size:35px;font-family:Comic Sans MS">Vision</h5>
            <p id="vision" class="wow bounceInUp">"Lorem ipsem Lorem ipsemLorem ipsemLorem ipsemLorem ipsemLorem ipsem</p>
            <h5 style="color:#446CB3;text-decoration:underline;font-weight:bold;font-size:35px;font-family:Comic Sans MS">Mission</h5>
            <p id="vision">"Lorem ipsemLorem ipsemLorem ipsemLorem ipsemLorem ipsemLorem ipsem"</p>
            <h5 style="color:#446CB3;text-decoration:underline;font-weight:bold;font-size:35px;font-family:Comic Sans MS">Objectives</h5>
            <p id="vision">"Lorem ipsemLorem ipsemLorem ipsemLorem ipsemLorem ipsemLorem ipsemLorem ipsem"</p><br><br><br>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div><br><br>
  
  <div class="row" >
  <div class="">
    <div id="aboutyou" class="wow bounceInUp section scrollspy">
      <div class="container">
        <h2 class="wow bounceInUp" style="text-decoration:underline;text-align:center;font-weight:bold;font-family:Comic Sans MS;color:red">About you</h2><br><br>
          <div class="wow bounceInUp">
            <h5 style="color:#446CB3;padding-top:30px;text-decoration:underline;font-weight:bold;font-size:35px;font-family:Comic Sans MS">Vision 1</h5>
            <p id="vision" class="wow bounceInUp">"Lorem ipsem Lorem ipsemLorem ipsemLorem ipsemLorem ipsemLorem ipsem</p>
            <h5 style="color:#446CB3;text-decoration:underline;font-weight:bold;font-size:35px;font-family:Comic Sans MS">Mission 1</h5>
            <p id="vision" class="wow bounceInUp">"Lorem ipsemLorem ipsemLorem ipsemLorem ipsemLorem ipsemLorem ipsem"</p>
            <h5 style="color:#446CB3;text-decoration:underline;font-weight:bold;font-size:35px;font-family:Comic Sans MS">Objectives 1</h5>
            <p id="vision" class="wow bounceInLeft">"Lorem ipsemLorem ipsemLorem ipsemLorem ipsemLorem ipsemLorem ipsemLorem ipsem"</p><br><br><br>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div><br><br>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick hack and I am able to do it. However, It would be great if anyone could let me know about error in my JS code since want to achieve same using plain javascript or jquery.