# Does animate.css support animation on scroll

Tags: javascript, css, animate.css, animate-on-scroll

I am using Animate.css on webpage and i was wondering if animate.css supports animation when user scrolls down the page. I came across [wow.js](https://github.com/graingert/WOW) but that seems to be very old script i was wondering if animate.css has build in support for scroll.

```
    <main class="animate__animated animate__fadeInLeft">
    <!-- Your code -->
  </main>
```

I was going through documentation of animate.css but i didnt find anything related to this

Comment: Consider https://stackoverflow.com/a/35312698/125981

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss, it using wow.js which i have mentioned in my question i am looking for any direct support from animation.css for scroll

Comment: 140+ you might sift through https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Banimate.css%5D+scroll

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss, I am using wow.js for now will search for any lightweight solution if possible, will check previous solution suggest but some of them are 10 year old..

Comment: Yes, might click that "Newest" there on the search

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74810616/3929620

Comment: You might want to see [this](https://kodingkhurram.github.io/animate.css-dynamic.demo/)